# HID Keyboard on Android 2.2

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-events, hid

I have been trying to get a USB HID keyboard working on an Android 2.2
and Android 2.3 tablet. I connected my device to a PC and the device
was enumerated as ADB device, this was visible in the Eclipse
environment. The logcat was providing me logs of the events on the
tablet. I was able to see that when I connect the USB HID keyboard to
the Android tablet, the device was getting enumerated. A USB hub event
was raised when I connect the device and when I remove the device.
However any keyboard input was not appearing on the tablet.

What I wanted to know is,

1) Is the enumeration happening at linux kernel level ?
2) Android 2.2 and 2.3 did not have support for USB HID device, does
that something has to be done in order to get it working ?

Comment: Refer this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 2.2 and 2.3 don't have USB support.  Some tablets/handsets support specific device classes, for instance some of the Archos internet tablets support keyboard, mouse and mass storage devices.

With the Archos tablets, you'd have to boot with the devices already attached in order for them to be detected.